# mongoosejs queries times just goes up... why?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this script for measuring the time it takes for a query to perform:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  (function(start) {

    Models.User.findOneAsync({
        userId: 'ABCD'
      }, 'age name location')
      .then(function(user) {
        logger.debug(Date.now() - start);
      })
  })(Date.now());
}
```

As a result, I'm getting an incremented list of results:

```
2015-05-19T11:09:16.204Z - debug: 4369
2015-05-19T11:09:16.205Z - debug: 4367
2015-05-19T11:09:16.205Z - debug: 4367
2015-05-19T11:09:16.206Z - debug: 4368
2015-05-19T11:09:16.206Z - debug: 4367
2015-05-19T11:09:16.206Z - debug: 4368
2015-05-19T11:09:16.206Z - debug: 4367
2015-05-19T11:09:16.206Z - debug: 4369
2015-05-19T11:09:16.206Z - debug: 4368
2015-05-19T11:09:16.206Z - debug: 4368
2015-05-19T11:09:16.206Z - debug: 4368
2015-05-19T11:09:16.206Z - debug: 4367
2015-05-19T11:09:16.212Z - debug: 4373
2015-05-19T11:09:16.212Z - debug: 4373
2015-05-19T11:09:16.248Z - debug: 4408
2015-05-19T11:09:16.376Z - debug: 4536
2015-05-19T11:09:16.459Z - debug: 4619
2015-05-19T11:09:16.475Z - debug: 4635
2015-05-19T11:09:16.493Z - debug: 4654
2015-05-19T11:09:16.552Z - debug: 4713
2015-05-19T11:09:16.636Z - debug: 4796
2015-05-19T11:09:16.794Z - debug: 4954
2015-05-19T11:09:16.830Z - debug: 4990
2015-05-19T11:09:16.841Z - debug: 5001
2015-05-19T11:09:16.845Z - debug: 5005
2015-05-19T11:09:17.133Z - debug: 5293
2015-05-19T11:09:17.176Z - debug: 5336
2015-05-19T11:09:17.182Z - debug: 5341
2015-05-19T11:09:17.230Z - debug: 5390
2015-05-19T11:09:17.421Z - debug: 5580
2015-05-19T11:09:17.437Z - debug: 5596
2015-05-19T11:09:17.441Z - debug: 5600
2015-05-19T11:09:17.513Z - debug: 5672
2015-05-19T11:09:17.569Z - debug: 5728
2015-05-19T11:09:17.658Z - debug: 5817
2015-05-19T11:09:17.697Z - debug: 5855
2015-05-19T11:09:17.708Z - debug: 5867
2015-05-19T11:09:17.712Z - debug: 5870
2015-05-19T11:09:17.732Z - debug: 5891
2015-05-19T11:09:17.805Z - debug: 5963
2015-05-19T11:09:17.852Z - debug: 6010
2015-05-19T11:09:17.890Z - debug: 6048
2015-05-19T11:09:17.985Z - debug: 6143
2015-05-19T11:09:17.989Z - debug: 6147
2015-05-19T11:09:18.013Z - debug: 6171
2015-05-19T11:09:18.016Z - debug: 6175
2015-05-19T11:09:18.031Z - debug: 6189
2015-05-19T11:09:18.170Z - debug: 6327
2015-05-19T11:09:18.196Z - debug: 6353
2015-05-19T11:09:18.205Z - debug: 6362
2015-05-19T11:09:18.209Z - debug: 6367
2015-05-19T11:09:18.224Z - debug: 6382
2015-05-19T11:09:18.317Z - debug: 6474
2015-05-19T11:09:18.360Z - debug: 6516
2015-05-19T11:09:18.369Z - debug: 6526
2015-05-19T11:09:18.433Z - debug: 6590
2015-05-19T11:09:18.460Z - debug: 6616
2015-05-19T11:09:18.513Z - debug: 6668
2015-05-19T11:09:18.541Z - debug: 6697
2015-05-19T11:09:18.553Z - debug: 6711
2015-05-19T11:09:18.586Z - debug: 6741
2015-05-19T11:09:18.672Z - debug: 6827
2015-05-19T11:09:18.688Z - debug: 6844
2015-05-19T11:09:18.693Z - debug: 6849
2015-05-19T11:09:18.729Z - debug: 6884
2015-05-19T11:09:18.817Z - debug: 6972
2015-05-19T11:09:18.823Z - debug: 6980
2015-05-19T11:09:18.828Z - debug: 6983
2015-05-19T11:09:18.882Z - debug: 7036
2015-05-19T11:09:18.919Z - debug: 7075
2015-05-19T11:09:19.016Z - debug: 7170
2015-05-19T11:09:19.020Z - debug: 7174
2015-05-19T11:09:19.043Z - debug: 7197
2015-05-19T11:09:19.066Z - debug: 7222
2015-05-19T11:09:19.177Z - debug: 7331
2015-05-19T11:09:19.182Z - debug: 7335
2015-05-19T11:09:19.189Z - debug: 7343
2015-05-19T11:09:19.189Z - debug: 7344
2015-05-19T11:09:19.191Z - debug: 7344
2015-05-19T11:09:19.280Z - debug: 7433
2015-05-19T11:09:19.340Z - debug: 7494
2015-05-19T11:09:19.344Z - debug: 7497
2015-05-19T11:09:19.358Z - debug: 7512
2015-05-19T11:09:19.362Z - debug: 7518
2015-05-19T11:09:19.455Z - debug: 7608
2015-05-19T11:09:19.499Z - debug: 7651
2015-05-19T11:09:19.504Z - debug: 7656
2015-05-19T11:09:19.515Z - debug: 7669
2015-05-19T11:09:19.569Z - debug: 7722
2015-05-19T11:09:19.574Z - debug: 7726
2015-05-19T11:09:19.574Z - debug: 7726
2015-05-19T11:09:19.667Z - debug: 7818
2015-05-19T11:09:19.672Z - debug: 7823
2015-05-19T11:09:19.678Z - debug: 7830
2015-05-19T11:09:19.689Z - debug: 7844
2015-05-19T11:09:19.716Z - debug: 7868
2015-05-19T11:09:19.835Z - debug: 7986
2015-05-19T11:09:19.839Z - debug: 7989
2015-05-19T11:09:19.845Z - debug: 7997
2015-05-19T11:09:19.978Z - debug: 8128
2015-05-19T11:09:19.989Z - debug: 8136
2015-05-19T11:09:19.995Z - debug: 8146
2015-05-19T11:09:19.999Z - debug: 8153
2015-05-19T11:09:20.012Z - debug: 8166
2015-05-19T11:09:20.023Z - debug: 8174
2015-05-19T11:09:20.026Z - debug: 8177
2015-05-19T11:09:20.116Z - debug: 8262
2015-05-19T11:09:20.127Z - debug: 8272
2015-05-19T11:09:20.136Z - debug: 8287
2015-05-19T11:09:20.154Z - debug: 8307
2015-05-19T11:09:20.179Z - debug: 8324
2015-05-19T11:09:20.262Z - debug: 8407
2015-05-19T11:09:20.275Z - debug: 8425
2015-05-19T11:09:20.279Z - debug: 8423
2015-05-19T11:09:20.306Z - debug: 8456
2015-05-19T11:09:20.309Z - debug: 8463
2015-05-19T11:09:20.396Z - debug: 8540
2015-05-19T11:09:20.422Z - debug: 8565
2015-05-19T11:09:20.424Z - debug: 8574
2015-05-19T11:09:20.441Z - debug: 8594
2015-05-19T11:09:20.452Z - debug: 8601
2015-05-19T11:09:20.455Z - debug: 8605
2015-05-19T11:09:20.461Z - debug: 8604
2015-05-19T11:09:20.549Z - debug: 8691
2015-05-19T11:09:20.555Z - debug: 8697
2015-05-19T11:09:20.565Z - debug: 8711
2015-05-19T11:09:20.598Z - debug: 8752
2015-05-19T11:09:20.602Z - debug: 8750
2015-05-19T11:09:20.659Z - debug: 8801
2015-05-19T11:09:20.689Z - debug: 8830
2015-05-19T11:09:20.701Z - debug: 8842
2015-05-19T11:09:20.707Z - debug: 8853
2015-05-19T11:09:20.712Z - debug: 8864
2015-05-19T11:09:20.752Z - debug: 8898
2015-05-19T11:09:20.798Z - debug: 8938
2015-05-19T11:09:20.829Z - debug: 8969
2015-05-19T11:09:20.844Z - debug: 8989
2015-05-19T11:09:20.850Z - debug: 8990
2015-05-19T11:09:20.869Z - debug: 9021
2015-05-19T11:09:20.880Z - debug: 9033
2015-05-19T11:09:20.893Z - debug: 9038
2015-05-19T11:09:20.939Z - debug: 9078
2015-05-19T11:09:20.965Z - debug: 9104
2015-05-19T11:09:20.979Z - debug: 9124
2015-05-19T11:09:20.984Z - debug: 9122
2015-05-19T11:09:21.051Z - debug: 9189
2015-05-19T11:09:21.057Z - debug: 9202
2015-05-19T11:09:21.057Z - debug: 9210
2015-05-19T11:09:21.096Z - debug: 9234
2015-05-19T11:09:21.112Z - debug: 9249
2015-05-19T11:09:21.121Z - debug: 9265
2015-05-19T11:09:21.130Z - debug: 9267
2015-05-19T11:09:21.133Z - debug: 9284
2015-05-19T11:09:21.195Z - debug: 9339
2015-05-19T11:09:21.200Z - debug: 9345
2015-05-19T11:09:21.239Z - debug: 9375
2015-05-19T11:09:21.247Z - debug: 9383
2015-05-19T11:09:21.270Z - debug: 9404
2015-05-19T11:09:21.283Z - debug: 9434
2015-05-19T11:09:21.334Z - debug: 9468
2015-05-19T11:09:21.337Z - debug: 9481
2015-05-19T11:09:21.348Z - debug: 9500
2015-05-19T11:09:21.352Z - debug: 9496
2015-05-19T11:09:21.378Z - debug: 9512
2015-05-19T11:09:21.385Z - debug: 9518
2015-05-19T11:09:21.416Z - debug: 9559
2015-05-19T11:09:21.419Z - debug: 9552
2015-05-19T11:09:21.470Z - debug: 9603
2015-05-19T11:09:21.475Z - debug: 9625
2015-05-19T11:09:21.490Z - debug: 9634
2015-05-19T11:09:21.517Z - debug: 9649
2015-05-19T11:09:21.522Z - debug: 9654
2015-05-19T11:09:21.554Z - debug: 9697
2015-05-19T11:09:21.562Z - debug: 9694
2015-05-19T11:09:21.575Z - debug: 9706
2015-05-19T11:09:21.622Z - debug: 9773
2015-05-19T11:09:21.635Z - debug: 9779
2015-05-19T11:09:21.656Z - debug: 9787
2015-05-19T11:09:21.683Z - debug: 9814
2015-05-19T11:09:21.688Z - debug: 9818
2015-05-19T11:09:21.691Z - debug: 9833
2015-05-19T11:09:21.716Z - debug: 9846
2015-05-19T11:09:21.720Z - debug: 9869
2015-05-19T11:09:21.751Z - debug: 9893
2015-05-19T11:09:21.778Z - debug: 9921
2015-05-19T11:09:21.786Z - debug: 9936
2015-05-19T11:09:21.790Z - debug: 9919
2015-05-19T11:09:21.820Z - debug: 9949
2015-05-19T11:09:21.830Z - debug: 9959
2015-05-19T11:09:21.864Z - debug: 10005
2015-05-19T11:09:21.870Z - debug: 9998
2015-05-19T11:09:21.884Z - debug: 10033
2015-05-19T11:09:21.928Z - debug: 10070
2015-05-19T11:09:21.931Z - debug: 10059
2015-05-19T11:09:21.949Z - debug: 10076
2015-05-19T11:09:21.984Z - debug: 10111
2015-05-19T11:09:21.987Z - debug: 10128
2015-05-19T11:09:22.015Z - debug: 10142
2015-05-19T11:09:22.019Z - debug: 10160
2015-05-19T11:09:22.046Z - debug: 10172
2015-05-19T11:09:22.060Z - debug: 10202
2015-05-19T11:09:22.064Z - debug: 10215
2015-05-19T11:09:22.089Z - debug: 10215
2015-05-19T11:09:22.123Z - debug: 10248
2015-05-19T11:09:22.130Z - debug: 10270
2015-05-19T11:09:22.152Z - debug: 10277
2015-05-19T11:09:22.156Z - debug: 10302
2015-05-19T11:09:22.180Z - debug: 10320
2015-05-19T11:09:22.183Z - debug: 10325
2015-05-19T11:09:22.186Z - debug: 10310
2015-05-19T11:09:22.228Z - debug: 10349
2015-05-19T11:09:22.260Z - debug: 10380
```

Ok, so it's not entirely increment  but it's going up forever...
I would expect to get a list of almost the same number (queries should take almost the same time).

Anyone knows why the times keeps going up?

Comment: You are not running the queries synchronously, they are asynchronous, therefore you are running 10000 queries in parallel. That will put a strain on your mongodb server.

Comment: Thanks @victorkohl but this wasn't my question. I know they run async... I just wanted to know why the query times keep going up?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not measuring *just* the query times.

The basic flow of this code is:

1. The `for` loop of 10000 iterations runs to completion, setting the start time for each iteration to the time each iteration occurred.
2. For the first 5 of those iterations (or whatever poolsize you're using with your MongoDB connection), their queries start as soon as their `findOneAsync` call is made.
3. As queries complete, their `findOneAsync` callbacks are put on the event queue and their connections are returned to the pool, allowing subsequent iterations' queries to start.

So all iterations' times include the time to complete the rest of the `for` loop after it, the time spent waiting for a connection in the pool to become available, and the time their `findOneAsync` callback spent waiting in the event queue.

If you want to get an accurate picture of how long the queries are taking, use MongoDB's [profiling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#database-profiling) support.

Comment: How big to you suggest a pull should be for all connections to run at the same time? Also, is there a better way to measure the query time?

Comment: @refaelos You'd have to use a pool size of 10000, which won't work because it's too big. Use profiling instead (see updated answer).

Comment: Yeah I guess... I'm looking for a way to find the best pool size for my servers. Today, even when I put a pool size of 1000 I get slow responses on some queries.